# Matplotlib confuses hours and days

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, timestamp

I'm trying to plot a pandas DataFrame with timestamps as index and int or float as columns:

| Time | Current_Gen1 | Current_Gen2 | Current_Gen3 | Current_100A_110V | Current_100A_220V | Current_shore_power | Gens_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 19:00:00 | 44.011111 | 0.0 | 42.833333 | 2.000000 | 19.055556 | -0.066667 | 86.844444 |
| 2022-04-01 20:00:00 | 44.522222 | 0.0 | 43.616667 | 2.000000 | 17.861111 | -0.155556 | 88.138889 |
| 2022-04-01 21:00:00 | 45.155556 | 0.0 | 44.705556 | 2.005556 | 18.616667 | -0.161111 | 89.861111 |
| 2022-04-01 22:00:00 | 45.972222 | 0.0 | 45.372222 | 2.000000 | 19.133333 | -0.277778 | 91.344444 |
| 2022-04-01 23:00:00 | 45.677778 | 0.0 | 45.755556 | 2.000000 | 20.744444 | -0.377778 | 91.433333 |

I down sampled it to the hour to have fewer points to display

**I want to display a major grid for the days and minor for the hours**

If let the default settings, I get this graph :

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv(r"data.csv", index_col=['Time'], parse_dates=['Time'])
df2 = df.resample('H').mean()

fig_gen_sum, axe = plt.subplots()
df2.plot(ax=axe, y='Gens_sum', grid=True)
```

[default graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRzVA.png)

**First issue**: I don't understand why there is one date with the full description

And when I'm using formatter to get the days :

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

df = pd.read_csv(r"data.csv", index_col=['Time'], parse_dates=['Time'])
df2 = df.resample('H').mean()

fig_gen_sum, axe = plt.subplots()
df2.plot(ax=axe, y='Gens_sum', grid=True)

xax = axe.get_xaxis()
xax.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d-%m'))
xax.set_major_locator(dates.DayLocator())
```

[day formatter graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Ews.png)

[zoomed formatter graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcSEJ.png)

**Second issue**: I'm getting a graph with days counted as hours if read it right

I've tried different configurations, but it always gives me weird result

I'm guessing the issue is with the formatting of my timestamps, but I can't find what

Comment: Use `x_compat=True` to undo the label aggregation: [Suppressing tick resolution adjustment in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#suppressing-tick-resolution-adjustment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tdy gave the response in the comment of the post

The solution is to set the option `x_compat=True` like:

```
df2.plot(ax=axe,x='time', y='Gens_sum', grid=True, x_compat=True)
```

As specified in pandas documentation

> Pandas includes automatic tick resolution adjustment for regular frequency time-series data. For limited cases where pandas cannot infer the frequency information (e.g., in an externally created twinx), you can choose to suppress this behavior for alignment purposes.

I can then get this result:

[image: Wanted result]

Everything else, including major and minor ticks works as well from there :

```py
fig_gen_sum, axe = plt.subplots()
df2.plot(ax=axe,x='time', y='Gens_sum', grid=True, x_compat=True)

xax = axe.get_xaxis()

xax.set_major_locator(dates.DayLocator())
xax.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%y/%m/%d'))
xax.set_minor_locator(dates.HourLocator(interval=5))
xax.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H h'))
```

Gives:

[image: Multi-ticks graph]